# How to make a view like this ? Actually I tried with drawable views but can't get it

Tags: android, layout, view

[image]

I want to make the design like image and also display same in phone and 7 inch tab.
I am using Linear layout by dividing the view in 5 part of the screen with using Framlayout draw a line but not possible to achieve like this image.

What's the other option like using canvas or any other better option.

First Image is displing expected result.
and other two are getting result.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<gradient
    android:angle="360.0"
    android:endColor="#A29AA4"
    android:startColor="#A29AA4" />
  </shape>
```

Below layout

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:weightSum="5">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/mView_circle1"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circleshape" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/mView_circle2"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"

                        android:background="@drawable/circleshape" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/mView_circle3"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"

                        android:background="@drawable/circleshape" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/mView_circle4"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circleshape" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/mView_circle5"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circleshape" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#A29AA4">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier and cleaner in canvas. Here is how you would do the first one.. You can replicate this with slight modifications for the other two.

Create a Canvas View:

```
public class CanvasView  extends View {

Paint bPaint;
RectF coordbounds;

public CanvasView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private void init()
{
    bPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    bPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas)

{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

     canvas.drawLine(coordbounds.left,coordbounds.centerY(),
     coordbounds.right,coordbounds.centerY(),bPaint);

    int circledia=20;

    //Divide the line into four segments and subtract 2 * half the      radii
    float actualspan = (coordbounds.right - coordbounds.left) - (2 *   circledia/2);
    //Segment the line into 3 parts
    float interlinesegments = actualspan/(4-1);
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(coordbounds.left + circledia/2 +
         (i*interlinesegments),
         coordbounds.centerY(),10,bPaint);
    }
 }

}
```

Create a layout to hold the view and call this view in your activity:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

    CanvasView view = new CanvasView(this);
    layout.addView(view);
```

oops, I forgot . :-) Please add this method in CanvasView class to declare the bounding box and set the layout:

```
@Override
 protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    float xpad = (float) (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
    float ypad = (float) (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());
    float coww = 0.0f, cohh = 0.0f, coll = 0.0f;
    init();
    coww = (float) w - xpad;
    cohh = (float) h - ypad;

    // Create a bounding box

    coordbounds = new RectF(0.0f,0.0f,
            coww,cohh);
}
```

EDIT : Change the above methods for bitmap

```
private void init()
{
    bPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    bPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.button);
}
```

Change onDraw as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas)

{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawLine(coordbounds.left,coordbounds.centerY(),
    coordbounds.right,coordbounds.centerY(),bPaint);

    int rectwidth=bitmap.getWidth();
    int rectheight=bitmap.getHeight();


    //Divide the line into four segments and subtract 2 * half the radii
    float actualspan = (coordbounds.right - coordbounds.left) - (2 * rectwidth/2);

    //Segment the line into 3 parts
    float interlinesegments = actualspan/(4-1);


    for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {


        float left= coordbounds.left + (i * interlinesegments);
        float top= coordbounds.centerY()-rectheight/2;
        float right = coordbounds.left+(i *    interlinesegments)+rectwidth;
        float bottom= coordbounds.centerY()+ rectheight/2;

       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,null,new RectF(left,top,right,bottom),null);


    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to change the Image on that circle view than is it possible?
Actually I want to this design for order processing of cart.

Comment: Yes, If you are using bitmaps - Look at canvas.bitmap method. Easiest way would be to use a circular bitmap. Provision four rectangles at desired  coordinates, you can use the same logic - just change radii to the half the width of  the rectangles. Now in canvas.bitmap, use these rectangles as your destination rectangles.

Comment: How?I can't understand

Comment: What sort of images do you have?

Comment: I have circular images and I want to set that on each circle as per the condition.
How can I set the src and destination in canvas.drawbitmap method?

Comment: Please check my edit which explains how to implement your req. with bitmaps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88210/discussion-between-varsha-venkatesh-and-kdoshi).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379378/how-to-put-textview-like-image-with-the-use-of-canvas

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of above code and previous code I made this Combination of circle shape and bitmap.

```
   @Override
    public void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas)

{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawLine(coordbounds.left, coordbounds.centerY(),
            coordbounds.right, coordbounds.centerY(), bPaint);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_myprofile);

    int rectwidth=bitmap.getWidth();
    int rectheight=bitmap.getHeight();


    //Divide the line into four segments and subtract 2 * half the radii
    float actualspan_image = (coordbounds.right - coordbounds.left) - (2 * rectwidth/2);

    //Segment the line into 3 parts
    float interlinesegments_bitmap = actualspan_image / (4 - 1);


    int circledia = 20;

    //Divide the line into four segments and subtract 2 * half the      radii
    float actualspan = (coordbounds.right - coordbounds.left) - (2 *   circledia/2);
    //Segment the line into 3 parts
    float interlinesegments = actualspan/(4-1);

    for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        float left= coordbounds.left + (i * interlinesegments_bitmap);
        float top= coordbounds.centerY()-rectheight/2;
        float right = coordbounds.left+(i *    interlinesegments_bitmap)+rectwidth;
        float bottom= coordbounds.centerY()+ rectheight/2;

        if(i==1){
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,null,new RectF(left,top,right,bottom),null);
        }else{
            canvas.drawCircle(coordbounds.left + circledia / 2 +
                            (i * interlinesegments),
                    coordbounds.centerY(), 10, bPaint);
        }


    }
}
```