# How to put textview like image with the use of Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, textview

I already implemented upper view with reference to this ans [How to make a view like this ? Actually I tried with drawble views but can't get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248421/how-to-make-a-view-like-this-actually-i-tried-with-drawble-views-but-cant-get/32305075#3230)[image]5075

I tried

```
     public class CanvasView extends View {

   Paint bPaint;
RectF coordbounds;
private Context mContext;

public CanvasView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
}

private void init() {
    bPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    bPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas)

{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawLine(coordbounds.left, coordbounds.centerY(),
            coordbounds.right, coordbounds.centerY(), bPaint);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_approved);

    int rectwidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int rectheight = bitmap.getHeight();


    //Divide the line into four segments and subtract 2 * half the radii
    float actualspan_image = (coordbounds.right - coordbounds.left) - (2 * rectwidth / 2);

    //Segment the line into 3 parts
    float interlinesegments_bitmap = actualspan_image / (5 - 1);


    int circledia = 20;

    //Divide the line into four segments and subtract 2 * half the      radii
    float actualspan = (coordbounds.right - coordbounds.left) - (2 * circledia / 2);
    //Segment the line into 3 parts
    float interlinesegments = actualspan / (5 - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        float left = coordbounds.left + (i * interlinesegments_bitmap);
        float top = coordbounds.centerY() - rectheight / 2;
        float right = coordbounds.left + (i * interlinesegments_bitmap) + rectwidth;
        float bottom = coordbounds.centerY() + rectheight / 2;

        if (i == 1) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(left, top, right, bottom), null);

            //canvas.drawLine(left, top, right, bottom, bPaint);

            Paint paint = new Paint();

            paint.setTextSize(20);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

            TextView nameTv = new TextView(mContext);

            nameTv.layout(0,0, (int)(coordbounds.left + circledia / 2 +
                          (i * interlinesegments)), (int)  coordbounds.centerY());



            nameTv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
            nameTv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            nameTv.setText("Consultation");

            nameTv.draw(canvas);

        } else {
            canvas.drawCircle(coordbounds.left + circledia / 2 +
                            (i * interlinesegments),
                    coordbounds.centerY(), 10, bPaint);


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `Canvas#drawText` doesn't work?

Comment: It works but alignment was not correct.

Comment: so change the alignment: `setTextAlign(Paint.Align align)`

Comment: but how?Please can you give me the value of Align?It doesn't show anything.
Paint.Align.CENTER

Comment: value of Align? it can be: LEFT, CENTER or RIGHT

Comment: it works, do you think you are the only one who finds it not working?

Comment: May be some another mistake done by me.I tried and than comment.

Comment: with no code i cannot say anything

Comment: It show me the content in between the two circles.Over the line.

Comment: with no code i cannot say anything

Comment: Code is described already in another question.Please review the question again.And I am using Relative layout for adding this canvas view.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248421/how-to-make-a-view-like-this-actually-i-tried-with-drawble-views-but-cant-get/32305075#3230

Comment: there is no code in your original question too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88753/discussion-between-kdoshi-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place the text do as follows in onDraw:

```
float midline_segment = (5-1)/2 * interlinesegments + rectwidth/2;
canvas.drawText("Order transmitted XYZ", 
coordbounds.left +  midline_segment, 
coordbounds.centerY()+40,tPaint);
```

Make sure that you set the alignment correctly in the Paint object:

```
tPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

Comment: hey It works like a charm but I want to know about it's fundamental.How can you calculate it?

Comment: If I want to do it dynamically than what should I do for this kind of calculation.
I want to do it for object 2,3 & 4.

Comment: We are using drawText (String text, float x, float y, Paint paint) method, x - will the x-coordinate of the point where the center of the text should be.. For example for object 2- You calculate the midline segment values as interlinesegment + rectwidth/2 - this is because it's only one hop away from the start which is coordbounds.left.  For the y position , I'm just offseting from the center of the bounding box which is center. To go up you have to subtract a certain value, to go down you have to add a certain value depending upon the distance. I would advise you to explore canvas..

Comment: Means I have to manage midline_segment statically as per index( Object )
or any dynamic way possibility is there.

Comment: I want to set the textview dynamically below the object.
You already help for the two object now I want to know midline_segment for the 4th object.

  float midline_segment2 =  interlinesegments + rectwidth/2;   //for 2nd object
                float midline_segment3 = (5-1)/2 * interlinesegments + rectwidth/2; //For 3rd object
                float midline_segment4 = midline_segment2 + interlinesegments + rectwidth/2; //For 4th object

like this

Comment: But can't get position of textview in 4th object.I want to combined this 4 line code into one line if possible otherwise it's ok for the conditionally statements.

Comment: Try : for i:0 to num_of_objects , midline_segment = (i * interlinesegments) + rectwidth/2

Comment: float midline_segment = coordbounds.left + circledia / 2 + (i * interlinesegments);
It also Works fine. By the way thank you very much for helping.